# XSLT: Test if node exists regardless if it's a child or grandchild of current node

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I'm working on some xslt transformations and I've just found out that there might or might not be an extra node between my current parent and it's clildren, depending on external factors. So now I have to change my xslt code in order to deal with both of these scenarios:

scenario 1:

```
<parent>
   <child/>
   <child/>
<parent>
```

scenario 2:

```
<parent>
   <nuisance>
      <child/>
      <child/>
   </nuisance>
<parent>
```

I have situations in which I `test="parent/child"` or otherwise use this format of accessing a parent/node.

I need something like `test="parent/magic(* or none)/child"`

They only way I know of that can solve this problem is to use:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="parent/child">
       <!-- select="parent/child"-->            
    </xsl:when>

    <xsl:otherwise>
       <!-- select="parent/*/child"-->      
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

But this will triple my code in size and will be a lot of manual labour...

Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not simply select the union of the two?

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="parent/child|parent/*/child"/>
```

This will select the correct nodes in both cases.

Comment: I DID NOT KNOW YOU COULD DO THAT :O ...I thought there might be something like this that you could do; I just didn't know the syntax and didn't know what to google for. Thanks :) By the way, what other symbols can you use this way? Is there also a `&` instead of `|`?

Comment: Although you can often read "|" as "or", it should actually be read as "union" - it selects the union of two node-sets. XPath 2.0 adds the operators "intersect" and "except" to find the intersection or difference of two node-sets (they are written as words). In XSLT 2.0 you can also use these operators within a step of a path: so you could write `parent/(.|*)/child` as the solution to your problem.

Comment: @lwburk: It seems that you misunderstood the question and proposed as a solution something (applying templates) that was not requested in the question. Thus, your answer may not be the right one and it is definitely not providing the optimal test. See more on this in my answer.

Comment: @Dimitre - This is getting silly. I did not misunderstand the question. The OP responded with excitement at my answer, which was also accepted. If you look at the comments in the OP's source it's clear that applying templates was what was desired.

Comment: @lwburk: I don't see any comments in the OP's source that applying templates on the union of all nodes that satisfy the condition was ever intended. As for silly -- I agree that applying templates on the union of nodes that satisfy the condition instead of just testing if the condition is satisfied -- can be considered silly.

Comment: Why do I suddenly feel sleepy?

Answer (score 0):

> I have situations in which I
>   `test="parent/child"` or otherwise use
>   this format of accessing a
>   parent/node.
>
> I need something like
>   `test="parent/magic(* or none)/child"`

**This expression may be faster**:

```
parent/child or parent/*/child
```

**than the expression**:

```
parent/child|parent/*/child
```

Almost any XPath engine will immediately stop the evaluation at the first occurence of `parent/child` or at the first occurence of `parent/someElement/child`

On the other side, the second expression selects the union of all `parent/child` and `parent/*/child` elements and there may be many such elements.

**Even worse is**:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="parent/child|parent/*/child"/>
```

A test, as the original question needs, is very different from applying templates on all nodes that match this test. Just testing for a condition can be significantly more efficient. The OP hasn't indicated in any way that the test is in any way connected to applying templates.

Comment: See the OP's comment in source: `<!-- select="parent/child"-->`. It was pretty clear to me that the OP desired to apply templates.